# Changed out radio and getting battery discharge error when engine running

Tags: kia, battery-drain, gps, forte

So today changed out my Kia radio that was in my Kia Forte 2020. Seems my country brought in the low spec model at the time.

This is the old radio:

[image]

I changed it out to the touch screen that usually comes with the Kia Forte 2020 models but since changing it out I am getting a "Battery Discharge Warning" on the touch screen radio itself. Please see below:

[image]

I am aware that this is displayed when the engine is off but it also comes up every 10-15 mins while driving. Could this be the device malfunctioning? Had no battery issues before this and am not currently having any, just adding that part. I also notice the date and time has a blank icon like this: --:-- and when I click it I get "GPS Antenna Open" Message:

[image]

Any one has any idea what is happening? Also to add, yes I have tried resetting the radio.

Answer (score 0):

The battery discharge warning is to let you know that playing your radio while the car is not running will drain your battery. To address the 'GPS antenna open' message and the blank date/time pull the media 15 amp fuse (see below) and let the car sit for 30 minutes and then replace the fuse. This should reset your radio, GPS antenna and date/time functions.

[image: Kia fuse box]

Comment: "The battery discharge warning is to let you know that playing your radio while the car is not running will drain your battery" I am aware but it is still ther even while driving. Is that normal?

Comment: That is not normal.  Try pulling the media fuse to see if that resets your radio and the messages you are receiving.  If the battery discharge warning is still there when your car is running then you likely have an alternator or battery issue.  Since your car should still be under warranty take it to the dealer to have them check the condition of the battery and alternator.

Comment: Well I pulled the fuse but same issue. Every 60 seconds the error still comes up while driving or engine running. I'll bring it to the dealer but I haven't been having any battery issue since buying a new battery in August 2021 with the old radio. Wondering if it is maybe the new radio is faulty. As for the antenna, I realized that there is no antenna connection to plug into the new radio but the old radio told time alright(had the option to set it manually). Old one didn't have an antenna connection when I looked at the back of it. I can live without the date time but the battery is an issue